# PHPUNIT Selenium 2 key "enter" submit wrong form in Firefox 22

Tags: firefox, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

Until now my testcase working fine on FF21 but after i updated to FF22 when im using "enter" button he submit all form instead of this element which is on focus.
There is part of my "code"

```
$this->byXPath("//*[@id=\"likes\"]/span")->click();
sleep(2);`enter code here`
$this->keys("some");
sleep(2);
$this->keys("\xEE\x80\x87"); //in FF21 after clicking the enter "some" was selected, now on FF22 its submit whole form
$this->byXPath("//*[@id=\"asSearch\"]")->click();
```

---

Just answered to myself. I changed

`$this->keys("\xEE\x80\x87"); //enter key`

to this
 `$this->keys("\xEE\x80\x86"); //return key`

its not the best solution but its work for me